# Awesome Notifications: Invalid notification I am using Awesome Notification package in flutter

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

```
E/Android: Awesome Notifications: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=basic_channel shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x11 color=0xff009688 vis=PRIVATE) (NotificationThread:58)
W/System.err(25254): me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.exceptions.AwesomeNotificationsException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=basic_channel shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x11 color=0xff009688 vis=PRIVATE)
W/System.err(25254): at android.app.NotificationManager.fixNotification(NotificationManager.java:606)
W/System.err(25254): at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(NotificationManager.java:585)
W/System.err(25254): at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:534)
W/System.err(25254): at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:510)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.managers.StatusBarManager.showNotificationOnStatusBar(StatusBarManager.java:86)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.threads.NotificationSender.showNotification(NotificationSender.java:260)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.threads.NotificationSender.doInBackground(NotificationSender.java:147)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.threads.NotificationSender.doInBackground(NotificationSender.java:32)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.threads.NotificationThread.runOnForegroundThread(NotificationThread.java:106)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.threads.NotificationThread.execute(NotificationThread.java:34)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.threads.NotificationSender.send(NotificationSender.java:101)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.AwesomeNotifications.createNotification(AwesomeNotifications.java:569)
W/System.err(25254): at me.carda.awesome_notifications.AwesomeNotificationsPlugin.channelMethodCreateNotification(AwesomeNotificationsPlugin.java:1274)
```

Comment: add more details of how you init your notifications

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour
page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to
ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your awesome notification plugin like the below-mentioned code?

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      // set the icon to null if you want to use the default app icon
      'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',
      [
        NotificationChannel(
            channelGroupKey: 'basic_channel_group',
            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
            channelName: 'Basic notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
            defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
            ledColor: Colors.white)
      ],
      // Channel groups are only visual and are not required
      channelGroups: [
        NotificationChannelGroup(
            channelGroupKey: 'basic_channel_group',
            channelGroupName: 'Basic group')
      ],
      debug: true
  );
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the extension of the image from the image path like this:

```
'resource://drawable/res_notf_icon'
```